# How to chain sequence of Hotkeys in Autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I've been searching for the last hour here and in ahk's forum with no success, although I am sure this has been done and asked already somewhere. Maybe I am using the wrong terminology but, here goes the question:

I would like to create a few shorcuts sequences such that pressing a key combination as `^k` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) enters a state where I have 1 second to press another key and get different results for each key.
Preferably, it would work by pressing and holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>k</kbd> and then {<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd>} while still holding <kbd>k</kbd>. And if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and release, it sends <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to the application in focus, as usual.

```
^k then a::does something (with ctrl pressed down)
^k then b::does something else (with ctrl pressed down)
^k alone::sends ^k as usual
```

For those that use sublime, the behaviour I am after is the same as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>b</kbd> toggles the side bar. (I am sure other editors have similar behaviour)

I appreciate your attention and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to have to be blunt now and just say it, the code in the accepted answer is going to give me nightmares. It's truly terrible.

Here's how it actually should be done:

```
^k::return

#If, A_PriorHotkey = "^k"
^a::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^b::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^c::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"
^d::ToolTip, % A_ThisHotkey " pressed with ^k"

^k up::SendInput, ^k
#If
```

Very conveniently done by creating context sensitive hotkeys and just checking what the previous hotkey was.

Should be quite simple and straight forward, but here's a explanation for it anyway:
First just create an empty hotkey for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to consume any presses to it and set `A_PriorHotkey`.
Then create the context sensitive hotkeys, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is still held down, it's going to be the previous hotkey. Otherwise its release, `^k up`, will be the previous hotkey.

This will work as asked, except for that 1 second window you described. I don't really get it. What is its purpose supposed to be? Sounded very useless to me, since `k` is going to need to be held down anyway. Would make sense if `k` could be released mid way.

If the 1 second window is somehow useful/needed, then will have to add a `A_TickCount` check in there. It wont complicate it too much more.

Answer (score 1):

So what code below does is after you press ctrl+k it loops 10 times and checks if "a" or "b" have been pressed and returns message box if either of them have been pressed. After 10 loops if neither of those 2 keys have been pressed 3rd message box is opened.

Strictly speaking you don't have to press all 3 keys together to get effect you want. After you press ctrl+k and loop starts you only have to press a or b to get the message box to pop out but since the timing is so fast I thought it should work as you imagined. If you really want all 3 keys to be pressed add get key state for k and ctrl as well but in my opinion it is unnecessary.

```
^k::
loop,10
  {
  AIsDown := GetKeyState("a",P)
  BIsDown := GetKeyState("b",P)
  KIsDown := GetKeyState("k",P)
  CtrlIsDown := GetKeyState("ctrl",P)
  if(AIsDown == "1")
    {
    msgbox % "A was pressed"
    break
    }
  if(BIsDown == "1")
    {
    msgbox % "B was pressed"
    break
    }
  if(A_Index == 10) or (KIsDown == "0") or (CtrlIsDown == "0")
    {
    msgbox % "Proceed with ctrl + k only"
    break
    }
  sleep,100
  }
```

Comment: interesting approach! The only downside it seems is that if I do want to send `^k` to an application, it will only get registered after 1 second... mitigating this downside was the reasoning behind checking if `k` is still held down. I believe I can adapt the script and break the loop if `ctrl` is released also with the GetKeyState() function. There is also the function `Input` that waits for a user input.  In any case, your approach is already very valuable

Comment: I updated the code. It should work correctly now. Now if you release ctrl or k earlier then 1 sec it will end the loop. Longest you have to wait now before the loop closes is 100milisec(1/10 of a second) or change timing to your liking.

Comment: that does seem to work fine so far. Thanks for your time and attention.